# How do I make the recursive function work?

Tags: haskell

I have here some simple haskell code that *rolls* two dices and sums up their values. I want to use that value to make a move on a monopoly board. I've decided to use a recursive function for that and another function for the first move. Problem is I declared the recursive function to take an IO Int type parameter and return a result of the same type. How do I go around this.
Note: I am new to Haskell.

```
import System.Random

firstMove :: IO Int
firstMove = do
  start   <- randomRIO (0, 0)
  current <- sumOfTwoDices
  return (start + current)

makeAmove :: IO Int -> IO Int
makeAmove firstMove = firstMove
makeAmove pos = do
   step <- sumOfTwoDices
   return (pos + step)

rollDice :: IO Int
rollDice = randomRIO (1, 6)

sumOfTwoDices :: IO Int
sumOfTwoDices = do
    dice1 <- rollDice
    dice2 <- rollDice
    return (dice1 + dice2)
```

It sees pos as Int even though I specified it to  receive IO Int type. Help appreciated

Comment: This is the whole code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is actually that `pos` is an `IO Int` even though `+` requires both its arguments are `Int`s. You can lift the addition over `pos` using `fmap`:

```
makeAmove :: IO Int -> IO Int
makeAmove pos = do
   step <- sumOfTwoDices
   fmap (+ step) pos
```

Comment: Hmm.. I seem to receive a warning that Pattern match(es) are overlapped in the second line of your snippet. Should I be worried? Other than that its fine

Comment: @user3402719 - You don't get it in my code, but yes in your original `makeAmove firstMove = firstMove` will always match which I assume you don't want. It's not clear what you're trying to do there.

Answer (score 1):

just so you get something *working* I cleaned it up a bit:

```
import System.Random

firstMove :: IO Int
firstMove = do
  -- randomRIO (0,0) will allways be 0 so start=0
  let start = 0
  current <- sumOfTwoDices
  return (start+current)

makeAmove :: IO Int -> IO Int
makeAmove pos = do
   cur  <- pos
   step <- sumOfTwoDices
   return (cur+step)

rollDice :: IO Int
rollDice = randomRIO (1,6)

sumOfTwoDices :: IO Int
sumOfTwoDices = do
    dice1 <- rollDice
    dice2 <- rollDice
    return $ dice1+dice2
```

but as I told you in your last question - you should not do everything inside the IO monad - rewritten it would look like this:

```
module Monoploy where

import System.Random

type Position = Int
type Steps = Int

start :: Position
start = 0

end :: Position
end = 79 -- please note: I don't know the number of tiles on monopoly so the 79 (80 positions) will obvious be wrong ;)

-- moves around the board / wraps back to start
move :: Steps -> Position -> Position
move s p = (p+s) `mod` (end+1)

randomMove :: Position -> IO Position
randomMove pos = do
  steps <- sumOfTwoDices
  return $ move steps pos

rollDice :: IO Steps
rollDice = randomRIO (1,6)

sumOfTwoDices :: IO Int
sumOfTwoDices = do
  dice1 <- rollDice
  dice2 <- rollDice
  return $ dice1+dice2

sampleMoveFromStart :: IO Position
sampleMoveFromStart = randomMove start
```